# How to start a new line?

Tags: php

I want to write a new line but it's just write at the end of the line and do not start a new line. I have a question: How to fix that?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$data=array($_POST['name'].",", $_POST['genger'].",",$_POST['age']."," ,$_POST['personalitytype']."," ,$_POST['OS']."," ,$_POST['min']."," , $_POST['max']);

file_put_contents('singles.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

Comment: You need a `."\n"` at the end of `$data`

Comment: @JayBlanchard The exact character(s) you need actually depend on the type of line break one wants to use, but apart from that correct.

Comment: True @arkascha, but since it looks to be a CSV text file I went with the immediate need.

Comment: That will most likely result in an invalid csv file sooner or later without any escaping...

Comment: @JayBlanchard I did as you said but it write in the file "Array" instead of the content i need

Comment: Why did you accept my answer and then change?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think he does not know very well how SO works because he accepted my answer, then yours and after again my answer. Maybe what he wants to do it is to give points to both of us.

Comment: Perhaps so @Error404

Comment: @JayBlanchard  i'm so sorry. I want to thank to both of you. I'm a newbie so i don't have much exp :)

Comment: @zexi123 I do not remember if you need more rep to upvote answers but you can do it on the arrows on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put on the last position of your array the breaking line `\r\n`.

Comment: How did you put it ? Did you put two double quotes `"\r\n"` to store them on the array?

Comment: :))) ok, i had a mistake. It Worked! Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @zexi123 You are welcome :). Please do not forget to accept the answer if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implode the array (once you fix the concatenation syntax errors) and add a line break to the end of the imploded line:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$data=array($_POST['name'].",". $_POST['genger'].",".$_POST['age'].",". $_POST['personalitytype'].",".$_POST['OS'].",".$_POST['min'].",". $_POST['max']);
$line = implode(',', $data)."\n"; // creates a comma separated line with a line break at the end

file_put_contents('singles.txt', $line, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much :) i tried and it work as my expectation :)